# Creating a cached counter path for large data lists in Firebase

Tags: list, caching, counter, firebase

Using Firebase to count the total records is done this way:

```
var table = new Firebase('http://beta.firebase.com/user/tablename');

table.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   var count = 0;
   snapshot.forEach(function() {
       count++;
   });
   //count is now safe to use.
});
```

Is there a way to avoid enumeration by having a cached counter in a different path?

I was thinking in some "counter" object which keeps the history of changes and the last computed value.

```
counter:
{   
    value: 672,
    history:    
    { 
         +2, -4, +1, +1, +1    
    }
}
```

in a transaction then:

- pick one history item, update the value, remove the history item.

Also who would be responsible of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [an example that combines the idea of a counter with an incremental, numeric ID](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/5ESSp/). For your use case, you could skip the ID portion, but the principles are still the same.

The core of this is a [transaction](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/transaction.html) that, when you create a new record, adds one to your counter:

```
var fb = new Firebase('http://beta.firebase.com');

// stores incremental id before adding record
function incRecord(data) {
    // increment the counter
    fb.child('counter/value').transaction(function(currentValue) {
        return (currentValue||0) + 1
    }, function(err, committed, ss) {
        if( err ) {
           console.error(err);
        }
        else if( committed ) {
           // if you want to pass the counter into the data, 
           // just use ss.val() here to fetch it
           addRecord(data); 

           // could also store an audit history about changes to the counter, assuming we had a user ID or something to that effect with this:
           // but you don't need this history to increment it
           // fb.child('counter/history/'+ss.val()).set(userId);
        }
    });
}

// creates new record
function addRecord(data) {
   // you could pass the record value here, I just set the value to "record #<id>"
   fb.child('records').push(data, function(err) {
      err && console.error(err);
   });        
}
```

Then invoke it by calling something like this:

```
incRecord({ hello: 'world' });
```